# Calling constructor of generic type in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following piece of code:

```
  public getProducts<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users')
      .pipe(
        map((entities) => {
          return entities.map((entity) => {
            return new T(entity);
          })
        }),
        catchError((err) => Observable.throw(err))
      );
  }
```

This line gives me an error: `return new T(entity)`;

How can I call the constructor of a generic type in TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`T` is just a type, types are erased at runtime, so types can never appear in expressions.

What you need to do is pass in the constructor of `T` instead.

```
  public getProducts<T>(ctor: new (p: Partial<T>) => T): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users')
      .pipe(
        map((entities) => {
          return entities.map((entity) => {
            return new ctor(entity);
          })
        }),
        catchError((err) => Observable.throw(err))
      );
  }
```

This implies you have a class defined for `T`. If there is no class then don't bother with `new T`. If `T` is an interface then the objects returned by the server will presumably satisfy the interface and nothing more needs to be done/